# Cryptic error in Solr logs

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm pushing some documents into Solr, I keep getting this weird error I don't understand in the logs:

```
VelocityResponseWriter 
Left side ($list.size($request.params.getParams('fq'))) of '>' operation has null value at footer.vm[line 10,&#8203; column 79]
```

I found that:

> The VelocityResponseWriter processes the Solr response and request context through Apache Velocity templating.

Which is not really helping. Any idea what this error means ?

Comment: Does this occur when you're indexing? That seems like an issue with an UI that you're using to browse the documents.

Comment: I'm doing both indexing and using the UI at the same time. I never considered it before but this could be a browsing related issue ! Thanks a lot !